# Change cursor style when drag and drop in css

Tags: php, css, wordpress, sorting

I make a drag and drop on image sorting, the code work very well, but now client want that when a user Drag row the cursor style is a "pointer".

Now default cursor style is "move". I change every where in css but in vain, no changing happen.

Can any one help with css.

Any suggestions.

Here is my code

```
<table class="widefat fixed" cellspacing="0" id="image_sort" style="width:100%; table-layout:inherit;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col" class="column-slug"><?php _e('Image','lgs') ?></th>
                <th scope="col"><?php _e('Image Links To','lgs') ?></th>
                <th scope="col" class="column-slug"><?php _e('Actions','lgs') ?></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col" class="column-slug"><?php _e('Image','lgs') ?></th>
                <th scope="col"><?php _e('Image Links To','lgs') ?></th>
                <th scope="col" class="column-slug"><?php _e('Actions','lgs') ?></th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>

        <tbody>

        <form method="post" action="options.php">
        <?php settings_fields('wp_logo_slider_images'); ?>
        <?php foreach((array)$wp_logo_slider_images as $image => $data) : ?>
            <tr id="list_item_<?php echo $image ?>" class="list_item">
                <input type="hidden" name="wp_logo_slider_images[<?php echo $image; ?>][id]" value="<?php echo $data['id']; ?>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="wp_logo_slider_images[<?php echo $image; ?>][file]" value="<?php echo $data['file']; ?>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="wp_logo_slider_images[<?php echo $image; ?>][file_url]" value="<?php echo $data['file_url']; ?>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="wp_logo_slider_images[<?php echo $image; ?>][thumbnail]" value="<?php //echo $data['thumbnail']; ?>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="wp_logo_slider_images[<?php echo $image; ?>][thumbnail_url]" value="<?php echo $data['thumbnail_url']; ?>" />
                <th scope="row" class="column-slug"><img src="<?php echo $data['thumbnail_url']; ?>" /></th>
                <td><?php //echo $image; ?><input type="text" name="wp_logo_slider_images[<?php echo $image; ?>][image_links_to]" value="<?php echo $data['image_links_to']; ?>" size="30" /></td>
                <td class="column-slug"><input type="submit" class="button-primary" value="Update" /> <a href="?page=wp_logo_slider&amp;delete=<?php echo $image; ?>" class="button">Delete</a></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="wp_logo_slider_images[update]" value="Updated" />
        </form>

        </tbody>
    </table>

<?php

function image_sort(){  
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
?>
<!--<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>-->
<?php 
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-sortable');
?>
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready( function(e) {
   jQuery('#image_sort').sortable({
            items: '.list_item',
            opacity: 0.5,
            cursor: 'move',
            axis: 'y',
            update: function() {
                var ordr = jQuery(this).sortable('serialize') + '&action=list_update_order';
                jQuery.post(ajaxurl, ordr, function(response){
                    //alert(response);
                });
            }
      });
});

</script>
<?php
    }
    add_action('admin_head','image_sort');

    function order_list(){
        global $wp_logo_slider_images;

        $list = $wp_logo_slider_images;
        $new_order = $_POST['list_item'];
        $new_list = array();

        foreach($new_order as $v){
            if(isset($list[$v])){
                $new_list[$v] = $list[$v];
            }
        }
        update_option('wp_logo_slider_images',$new_list);
    }
    add_action('wp_ajax_list_update_order','order_list');
?>
```

Comment: provide the css coding that you tried

Comment: cant help without the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done using [`:active`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3aactive) pseudo class.

```
div{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
}

div:active{
    cursor: pointer !important;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/QygLh/)**

Comment: @Nadeem use `!important` because you are applying `cursor: move` using jquery before. I updated my post.

Comment: ok thanks alot @Mr_Green, now i got it where i go wrong, because i copy and past code so i not get it. IN JQUERY - cursor: 'pointer',. And its work Fine now. :)

Answer (score 1):

Why you can't Use jQuery. To change cursor style

### Using jQuery

### check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3WLGt/140/)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('a.clickme').click(function(){
    jQuery('body').css('cursor', 'pointer');
      $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
  });
});
```

### Using CSS

#### check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3WLGt/143/)

HTML

```
<div>
    <a href="#" class="clickme">Link1</a><br />
    <a href="#" class="clickme">Link2</a><br />
    <a href="#" class="clickme">Link2</a>  <br /> 
</div>
```

CSS

```
div{
    width: 200px;
    height:100px;
    border:1px solid #000;
}

div:hover, div:active{
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: I gave the css solution already. It doesn't mean I hold authority of it but just want to know what is the point of posting it again?

Comment: bro i think you not got my point, i see your jsfiddle link and this is not i want

Comment: @Mr_Green sorry but Nadeem say me not want anymore jQUery so i m show another way using CSS.

Comment: ok @JayPatel i doing wrong in jQuery not in css and now its working fine - thanks alot for your timing